# if else statement in one line using && and ||

Tags: shell-script

I would like to know if these 2 ways are equivalent:

First:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -x $FILE ]
then
  echo "You have execution permission to a "$FILE""
else
  echo "You don't have execution permission to a "$FILE""
fi
```

Second:

```
#!/bin/bash
[ -x $FILE ] && echo "You have execution permission to a "$FILE"" || echo "You don't have execution permission to a "$FILE""
```

Comment: Your quoting is wrong: `[ -x "$FILE" ]`; `echo "You have execution permission to '$FILE'"`

Comment: Ok thanks, but seems my code is working the same way(maybe inconsistent with standard :))
But are these 2 ways equivalent?

Comment: Whether your version works depends on it whether the file name contains whitespace (or, more precise: `IFS` characters).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The structures are not equivalent in general but in this case they are. The reason is that `echo` always has exit code 0. If that was a command instead which can exit with a code greater than zero then "the other branch" would be executed, too. This is impossible in the `if` case.

Comment: The `if` case is also much more readable.

Comment: @user3014282: To elaborate Hauke's answer, `[ -e /tmp ] && { echo 1 ; false ; } || echo 2` will print both `1` and `2`. Recasting the same using `if ... then ... else ... fi` will print only `1`. So `&&` `||` is not an exact equivalent of the other.